# Datatable server sideprocessing

Tags: jquery, python, html, datatable, flask

I have a datatatble and one column is editable. I am looking for solution of 3 problems. Can anyone help on this.

1. I need to pass the the first column to my server-side script (that is the primary key of the DB)
2. I need to make only one cell as immutable (element in firstrow, first column)
3. After editing the table I need to see the edited value in the column. I know if we use sUpdateURL: function(value, settings) will display the changes. Can anyone help me on this. I am very new to the datatatble.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#jtable').html( '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="pretty" id="edit_table"></table>' );
        $("#edit_table").dataTable({
            "aaData": {{ result | safe }},
            "aLengthMenu" : 100,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "aoColumns" : [
                {'sTitle' : 'Options' },
                {'sTitle' : 'Values'}
            ],
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "bFilter" : false,
            "bSearchable" :false,
            "bInfinite" :true,
            "bSort" :false,
            "bPaginate": false
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#edit_table").dataTable().makeEditable({
             sUpdateURL: "/submitchanges",
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                {
                },
                {
                    indicator: 'Saving platforms...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to edit platforms',
                    type: 'textarea',
                    submit:'Save changes',
                    fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings){

                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Am using python + flask framework for server side processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here server code that works with your client side (slightly modified, see below):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request as flask_request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    aa_data = [['First', 'Second'], ['First', 'Second']]
    return render_template('index.html', result = aa_data)

@app.route('/update/', methods=['POST'])
def update_records():
    value = flask_request.form['value']
    row_id = flask_request.form['rowId']
    # todo: perform database update operation
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Client side modifications:

```
$("#edit_table").dataTable().makeEditable({
            sUpdateURL: "/update/",
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                {
                    sName:"secondColumn"
                }
            ]
        });
```